# Random nextInt() not working fine, better way to get random numbers?

Tags: java, android, random

I need to get a random number between two integers. I'm using this function to get it:

```
     public int randInt(int min, int max) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
     }
```

The problem is that sometimes the function is not working fine, because it is giving me chains of numbers with very low difference, for example, i'm calling the function with min 0 and max 1000, and sometimes i get these values in a chain: 500, 500, 502, 500, 500, 500, 520, 530, 503, 500, 500, 501 etc...

Sometimes the function works fine, and i get values with a lot of difference, for example, 1, 20, 500, 200, 444, 850, 664, etc...

So... i need a function that returns real random numbers allways, and not sometimes...

There is a better way to achieve this? with a min and max values for the random?

thanks

Comment: With those kinds of result, it does not look like you're passing what you think you're passing (as min-max values). Check your arguments if it's really 0 and 1000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't reinitialize `Random` on every invocation and you could use [`SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) if you want more "secure" randomness.

```
private static Random rand = new SecureRandom();
public int randInt(int min, int max) {
    // Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    return randomNum;
 }
```

Comment: It's worth noting that secureRandom won't be "more random" from a statistical point of view (and isn't the problem here), its just harder to reverse engineer the way in which it isnt "truly" random

Comment: +1 Good catch. I didn't realise that problem is in re-instantiating of Random class in every call. Now it does make sence.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're calling the method. If the arguments are close to each other (say `min` is 500 and `max` is 525, your outputs will all be in a very close range. If the arguments are far apart (say `min` is 0 and `max` is 1000, your outputs will vary a lot.

The method itself works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the current time and multiply with let's say the last digit. That will give you some more random.

I don't have any code available but it sounds like getCurrentime()

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is creating a new `Random` object with each invocation. Create one and only one instance of `Random` per program, then poll from it as often as needed.  Think of it as similar to a well for water - you don't dig a new well each time you need a drink.  The default initialization is taken from the clock, historically at the millisecond level, and on modern machines you can instantiate multiple instances with the same initialization which will therefore produce the same values.

Using time will **NOT** give random results in general, and crypto quality randomness is overkill unless you're actually doing crypto.